# error C2440: 'return': cannot convert. Does work with vs140,141 but not vs142

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I looked through the suggestions but could not find the likes of my error. I ran into this with vs141 and fixed it, I believe by changing the `c++ ISO Standard` in VS. I may have been too hasty in uninstalling VS2017 when I installed VS2019, so I can't go back to see what I did. It just works with vs140 which I do still have installed. This code will produce the vs142 error:

```
struct t1{
    t1 append() { return t1(); }
};

struct t2 : public t1{
    t2(t1&te):t1(te){}
    t2 add() { return t1().append(); } //error C2440
};
```

In my case, t1 is from another library, and I'm wrapping it with t2. I've tried all the variants of `c++ ISO Standard` in VS2019, but the error persists.

To add to my confusion, I've compiled another project that uses the same code with VS2019, and no error! [This Code, line 36](https://github.com/lakeweb/ECAD/blob/master/project/include/xml.h). (Note, now there is a problem with boost::fusion and boost::spirit::x3. But that is something else).

What I am doing may be illegal, but when it works, it works fine. And as I don't know for sure, I think it should be fine.

Comment: The only thing I could think of that makes this standard legal would be to change `t2(t1&te):t1(te){}` to `t2(const t1&te):t1(te){}`

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running this code through a different compiler (such as GCC or Clang) the error message is a bit more helpful:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 't1&' to an
>   rvalue of type 't1'
>
> ```
>  t2 add() { return t1().append(); }
> ```

This tells you the exact cause:

```
t2(t1&te):t1(te){}
```

Accepts a non-`const` reference, which cannot be a temporary object, such as returned by `append()` - *but* a `const` reference can accept a temporary object, so changing this constructor to

```
t2(const t1&te):t1(te){}
```

fixes the problem (and is standard compliant as well)

Comment: Thanks! That does fix it. Why vs142 caught it in two places but not a third... I learned something. And a heads up about the error reporting of Microsoft. There was never mention of `const` in the error message.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when enabling language extensions and using `/W4` instead, MSVC will also warn about the non-`const` reference: https://godbolt.org/z/E6kMj9 - apparently disabling language extension messes with the error detection/reporting